# Safari Timing Out On Certain AWS API Gateway Endpoints

Tags: reactjs, safari, aws-lambda, axios, aws-api-gateway

I have bunch of AWS Lambda functions behind an AWS API Gateway with a custom authorizer Lambda function and they are being hit by a React front end using Axios for making requests. For some reason, everything works fine on Chrome and Postman but Safari times out on a select few endpoints. I've tested to see if the API Gateway was timing out by setting the API Gateway timeout to 5000 ms and the front end timeout to 10000 ms. The requests timeout at 10000 ms, leading me to believe that the front end isn't even reaching the API Gateway but I'm still left trying to figure out what exactly is going on.

I know this isn't a lot to go on but if this sounds familiar to anyone, I'd love to hear your experience so I can get this thing sorted.

Thanks!

EDIT: We have done some more testing and it seems that Safari is preventing requests from succeeding when an iframe is present on the page. If it helps, the src of the iframe has the same domain as the parent page but a different subdomain. When an iframe is present, no requests to our API seem to be completing.

Comment: is your lambda placed inside a vpc?

Comment: It is not. I avoid that because it increases cold start times a lot. We've done further testing and it seems like Safari is only timing out requests on pages that have iframes on them. I'm pretty certain at this point that it is a front end error but I don't know what exactly it is.